# Wrench to be used with a bottom bracket tool?

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools, mechanical

[image: tool to identify]

It looks like a wrench with a cup at the endpoint. I was wondering what is this tool called and whether it's meant to be used by itself or in combination with a bottom bracket tool, like the PT BBT-22, for example.

Comment: the matte/pearl parts are ordinary socket set. The shiny splined part just visible is the bottom bracket tool. The socket looks too big (compared to my bottom bracket tool https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dynamic-2017-Mountain-Bike-Bicycle-Bottom-Bracket-Remover-Removal-Repair-Tool-For-Shimano-Mar08/32796157758.html)

Comment: We generally just use a large adjustable wrench.

Comment: A 12" adjustable spanner/wrench/crescent is all I use on my BB tool.  Sometimes with a length of  steam pipe for additional leverage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tools being used there are:

- Bottom bracket tool
- Large socket to engage with the large hex head on the BB tool
- [Sliding T-handle socket driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=sliding%20t%20handle%20socket&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

Some bottom bracket tools such as the Park BBT-22 have a 3/8 socket drive built in, so the large socket isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 32mm socket with a bar attached instead of a ratched.

So you should be able to use a 32mm socket with a ratchet with the PT BBT-22.

Comment: do you believe it's two pieces, a socket and a bar?

Comment: I know I can use a 32mm socket with the BBT-22, it says it on the Park Tool. For my question, I am actually curious to know what that specific wrench is.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a Bar or Sliding T-Handle Socket Driver as Argenti Apparatus mentioned